# Passing realmobject with parcel to activity has return null

Tags: realm, parcel

can anyone help me with my problem with passing realmobject with parcel to another activity and in second activity my object is null?

In Activity i get instatne of class Category from tag.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, CategoryListActivity.class);
        Category category = (Category)v.getTag();
        Log.e("Id", " "+category.getId()); //this is ok it prints 1
        Parcelable parcelable = Parcels.wrap(category);

        intent.putExtra("category", parcelable);
        startActivity(intent);
```

And in class CategoryListActivity v method onCreate is code

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Category category = Parcels.unwrap(intent.getParcelableExtra("category"));
Category category1= Parcels.unwrap(getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("category"));
Log.e("Id 1", " "+category.getId()); //retun 0
Log.e("Id 1", " "+category1.getId()); //return 0
```

And this print 0 and i rly dont know why is 0. Can anyone has some suggestion to resolve this? thx, or if its necessery insert my Entity which extend RealmObject i can paste

Comment: Send its primary key through the intent and and query the object in your other activity. What version of Realm are you using? There were major changes to the way proxy classes work in 0.88.0.

Comment: i did it but i just want to know if its possible to do it. I have 0.88.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not send RealmObjects in a Parcel unless they are un-managed or standalone objects.

It is a lot safer to just send the ID value and query for the object on the other side: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#intents

If you want to user Parceler. Have you configured your objects as described here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#parceler

Comment: Oki :) thanks a lot i just wanted to know if its possible cause i rly didnt know about it and i spent 3 hours to resolve this